# Can Emacs open a serial connection behind tramp?

Tags: tramp

Using for example `serial-term`, or in lisp `make-serial-process` one can open a serial port within Emacs. But both will fail if the tty is access on a remote computer thought tramp.

Is there any alternative to using a remote Emacs for this?

Comment: On a similar note, we can't use TRAMP paths even for local serial devices (e.g. `/su::/dev/ttyS0`), which I could imagine as coming in handy if the device's permissions won't normally let you use it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you are trying to achieve? [Tramp over serial line](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/58zieq/still_cant_get_over_how_powerful_tramp_is/d94j7ic/) or something another?

Comment: it's serial line over tramp: the tty is not on the local computer, but on another computer. I've a device controlled by serial line, connected to a remote computer, and I want to control it from my local computer. I can do it in shell using ssh then Emacs then serial-term, but I can't control it from my local Emacs then tramp then serial-term.

Answer (score 2):

Tramp doesn't support this, and I have also no plans to implement. But if somebody wants to volunteer an implementation, pls contact me or the the Tramp ML tramp-devel@gnu.org.

Comment: Could this be implemented without knowing `C`?

Comment: Don't know, haven't investigated yet. But if it goes into Tramp it must be `Lisp`.